# Drive API V3 - Java - buildHttpRequest throws IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, google-api, google-drive-api

I'm using Drive API V3 to create (upload) files in Google Drive with Java (google-api-services-drive v3-rev136-1.25.0).

I wrote the following code to set an unsuccessful response handler (EBO):

```
HttpRequest httpRequest = driveService.files().create(fileMetadata, fileContent).setFields("id").buildHttpRequest(); // IllegalArgumentException!

httpRequest.setUnsuccessfulResponseHandler(buildExponentialBackOff());

HttpResponse httpResponse = httpRequest.execute();
```

But a java.lang.IllegalArgumentException is thrown when I try to create the request - buildHttpRequest() -

With folders' creation there's no problem, instead. The following code works properly:

```
HttpRequest httpRequest = driveService.files().create(folder).setFields("id").buildHttpRequest();

httpRequest.setUnsuccessfulResponseHandler(buildExponentialBackOff());

HttpResponse httpResponse = httpRequest.execute();
```

I cannot understand why an IllegalArgumentException is thrown when I try to create an upload request.

Thank you.

Comment: There's no explanation in the exception? This is why I avoid libraries. 
Sorry I have no answer, but out of curiosity, how many times will buildExponentialBackoff() backoff before failing, and which status values will cause a backoff (403, 500, 501, 503)?

Comment: There's no explanation and the IllegalArgumentException is thrown before execute().